# Standard ML permutations

Tags: smlnj, ml, sml

I am working on a function to the permutations for all values in a list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//MY ROTATE FUNCTION

fun rotate e [] = [[e]]
| rotate e (x::xs)= (e::x::xs)::(List.map (fn l => x::l) (rotate e xs));

//MY CURRENT PERMUTATION FUNCTION

fun perm [] = []
| perm (x::xs) = List.concat(List.map (fn l => (rotate x xs)) xs) @ perm xs;
```

OUTPUT:

```
- perm [1,2,3];

val it = [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[2,3],[3,2]]
```

The output should be something like [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]. As you can see I am missing something here. I believe the issue is my 3 is not being passed to rotate as rotate 3 [1,2] is what I am missing from my code along with two 2 element lists being here for some reason.

How can I correct my perm function to show the output correctly? Any help no matter how big or small would help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the rotate approach is the one you'll want to take. Rather, as [Shivindap describes here](http://shivindap.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/permutations-of-a-list-in-haskell/), a good way to do this sort of this is to pull the first element from the argument list, and append it to all permutations of the tail. **Rinse and repeat** this for every element of the list, and you'll end up with all the permutations.

You'll find an in depth explanation of this approach [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=485066). For code samples in ML, you could also [check this out](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sak/courses/ilcs/ass1-moss/512749638/match10-1.html).

Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple fix for your attempted solution. You were nearly there.

```
fun interleave x [] = [[x]]
| interleave x (h::t) =
    (x::h::t)::(List.map(fn l => h::l) (interleave x t))

fun permute nil = [[]]
| permute (h::t) = List.concat( List.map (fn l => interleave h l) (permute t))
```